# Unable to configure Application Insights Status Monitor on Live IIS Web App

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

Application Insight is working perfectly fine on local dev but giving issue on server with the Status Monitor. Following is the error:

> The application is using an older version of Application Insights for
>   the Visual Studio Online. Remove ApplicationInsights.config and
>   Application Insights Nuget package references from your project and
>   Application Insights to your project using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3
>   or later.

I followed above instruction same result. Mainly I followed this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now) but I have also tried the following:

- Make a copy of ApplicationInsights.config if you customized ApplicationInsights.config.
- In Solution Explorer, right-click your project and choose Manage NuGet packages.
- Select Browse.
- Search for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web, select it and choose Install/Update. You need version 2.2.0 (or later).
- Reinstate any customizations you made to ApplicationInsights.config. Most of the changes you'll see when you compare the files are because we removed some modules and made others parameterizable.
- Rebuild your solution.

It didn't work.

Comment: when you deploy, are you properly deploying all the new nuget packages/etc?  are there leftover old versions still left behind?

Comment: @JohnGardner I have deleted all the files and deployed things from scratch. It didn't worked.

Comment: what version of status monitor?